# 16.04 replacing folders instead of merging them

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon, nemo

When I try to copy a folder into a directory where an older version of that folder already exists, say when backing up a folder to an external hard drive, this window pops up:

[image]

Is there a way to also have a *Replace* option? Because merging will keep all the files in the older folder that I have deleted in the newer one, which is not always preferable.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon and Nemo as the default file manager.

Comment: This is not possible AFAIK. You need more advanced tools, like the command line tool `rsync`.